# Docker could not start after install on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos7

I install docker on CentOS7(Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64) with command `yum install -y docker`, but when I try to start docker with `systemctl start docker`, the docker failed to start, below is the error message

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-03-15 16:38:37 CST; 10s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5166 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY $REGISTRIES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5166 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 15 16:38:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 15 16:38:36 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[5166]: time="2018-03-15T16:38:36.570661801+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd... 5171"
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[5166]: time="2018-03-15T16:38:37.585565695+08:00" level=warning msg="overlay2: the ba...
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain dockerd-current[5166]: Error starting daemon: SELinux is not supported with the overlay2 graph ...false)
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 15 16:38:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you just `yum update kernel`. Which kernel are you running Docker on?

Comment: @MichaelZukowski  I've tried `yum update`, but no help for me

Comment: What's your Docker version, kernel version?